# Equivalent solution to soldering STM32F103C8T6 Board

Tags: stm32, soldering, pins

There is this project I am doing and part of it I will be using a STM32F103C8T6 Board.
Unfortunately, I do not have a soldering kit as i for now I cannot solder the pins of the board.

Is there an equivalent solution to this? Like buying on online that is already soldered or is there anything else that I could buy and then it would not be necessary to solder the pins.

I would most probably order the stuff from amazon/ebay in Germany

Comment: Buying recommendations are considered off topic. But search for stm32 discovery kits

Comment: You're not going to get far without the ability to do simple soldering occasionally.   Maybe see if you can find a makerspace or a friend.

Answer (score 1):

Just maybe:

[This digikey search](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/development-boards-kits-programmers/evaluation-boards-embedded-mcu-dsp/786?FV=-8%7C786&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&k=STM32F103&pageSize=25&pkeyword=STM32F103)  lists all development boards with a STM32F103 in. How well these match the STM32F103C8T6 is tbd.

[This](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/NUCLEO-F103RB/497-14362-ND/4695527) $US11 development board MAY come close enough to suit your need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Purchasing advice is considered off topic here, but consider this development board
https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f103rb.html

Comment: +1 I now see you found the same board I did. (Downvote from somebody else offset :-).